# Android - Three layouts for one activity

Tags: android, layout, layout-inflater

I have three layouts and one activity. One layout is "main" for the activity - it is divided into two vertical sections - one, which is always the same (something like a header) and second is a ListView where I've already add second layout (with LayoutInflater).

BUT: Is there any way how to add third layout? I cant find any answer how to do this with LayoutInflater.

EDIT:
As Dave wrote, I want thees three parts on one screen:

```
Header (something what is always the same - main.xml)
-----------------------------------------------------
ListView (data from DB - everytime it may be a different number of rows - items.xml)
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Another Listview (the same as above but different data - another_items.xml)
-------------------------------------------------------
Buttons (some buttons - main.xml)
```

I have done everything except the "Another Listview" part. I don't know how to include it.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? Your `Activity` can only have one layout, but this one layout can consist of a lot of sub-views.
Maybe if you added your code so far, the question will become more clear.

Comment: Yes please clarify what you are trying to accomplish, because based on what you said so far, I thinking you might need to take a step back. Also look into fragments.

Answer (score 0):

are you looking for something like:

```
header
- - - - - - - - - - - -
listview
- - - - - - - - - - - -
third layout group?
```

Comment: Header - Listview - another Listview => That's what I want